# Netezza SQL - give a parameter

Tags: sql, sas, netezza

```
SELECT to_char(START_D,???)
```

The issue I have above is that I can't seem to find the right parameter for the above to work.
The date is numeric e.g 1102. I want to turn this into a character.

Actually even better is to turn the numeric field to 11/02, which is Day/Month. The reason why I want to turn it into character is that it outputs without the zeros in front. e.g 712 instead of 0712.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, Netezza uses a variant of PostgreSQL. If so, try:

```
to_char(START_D,'DD/MM')
```

to turn a date into a day/month string.

To turn a 4-digit integer into a slash-separated string, try:

```
substring(to_char(START_D,'9999'),2,2)||'/'||substring(to_char(START_D,'9999'),4,2)
```

Replace the `'9999'` with `'0000'` if you want 3-digit integers to be 0-padded.

Comment: Problem is: `START_D` is an int, not a date

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - see amended answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Thats what I need. I changed the '9999' to '0000' to give the zero in front.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
to_char(START_D, '0000')
```

Comment: Thanks it turned it into character with the zeros in front. Any ideas how to get the '/' in there? e.g. 11/02 from 1102.